# Jitsi_meet Crash and Technical Difficulties using Flutter

Tags: flutter, jitsi-meet

am currently using this package in a release version for my user and it's on playstore.

But there are some few technical issues that my users are having

1. Some device can't open the meeting
2. Some device are able to open the meeting but got stuck at "Connecting you to meeting"
3. When two participants are in the meeting the jitsi package it's saying "No Audio device is available" But Audio device is always available
4. Sometimes when pass meeting ID it does show null when meeting start.

**Package Name**

> jitsi_meet_wrapper: ^0.0.5

Below are screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you display the meeting name "ooh father, I pray for.. " at the top center please?